# What type does `getBoundingClientRect()` return?

Tags: typescript

What type does `getBoundingClientRect()` return? I have the following errors:

```
var logo1: HTMLElement = document.getElementById('test'); 
var logo1TextRectangle: DOMRect = logo1.getBoundingClientRect(); <- error
```

error TS2304: Cannot find name 'DOMRect'.

I watch this https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getBoundingClientRect

---

```
var logo1TextRectangle: nsIDOMClientRect = logo1.getBoundingClientRect(); <- error
```

error TS2304: Cannot find name 'nsIDOMClientRect'.

and this https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Tech/XPCOM/Reference/Interface/nsIDOMClientRect

---

I know I can just use this:

```
var logo1TextRectangle: any = logo1.getBoundingClientRect();
```

but can anybody tell me what is the returned type, or tell me a link where I can take a look to the returned types.

*Non native English speaker*

Answer (score 37, accepted):

> What kind returns getBoundingClientRect()

It returns `DOMRect`:

```
const logo1: HTMLElement = document.getElementById('test'); 
const logo1TextRectangle: DOMRect = logo1.getBoundingClientRect();
```

## More

FWIW you can let the compiler infer it for you :

```
const logo1: HTMLElement = document.getElementById('test'); 
const logo1TextRectangle: DOMRect = logo1.getBoundingClientRect();
```

And if you hover over the variable you will see that its correctly inferred:

[image]

Comment: Thanks, I'll have to use a compiler to view the types, which now use it tells me nothing.

Comment: in WebStorm, hold CTRL down and hover over the variable, or just over `.getBoundingClientRect()`. It actually says `ClientRect | DOMRect` (in my installation).  
`DOMRect` is specified at [MDN getBoundingClientRect()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getBoundingClientRect), but see the [notes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getBoundingClientRect#Notes) about `ClientRect` and compatibility there.

Comment: `ClientRect` is deprecated. `DOMRect` workedforme